# ld cannot find library right in front of it

Tags: gcc, libraries, linker

I'm trying to build a rust program that involves `diesel` with `postgresql` on `Fedora 31` and the build fails because the linker can't find `libpq`.
As it's reproducible with `gcc`, I'm using `gcc` to keep the question shorter.

```
gcc -L /lib64 -lpq
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
```

```
ls /lib64 | grep libpq
libpq.so.5
libpq.so.5.11
```

```
ldd /lib64/libpq.so.5
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc06ddd000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f4885ea7000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f4885bc7000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f4885b75000)
        libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f4885b1d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4885afb000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4885932000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f4885916000)
        libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f488590f000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f488581e000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f4885805000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f48857fe000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f48857ec000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f48857e3000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f48857ca000)
        liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f48857b9000)
        libsasl2.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007f4885799000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4885f8c000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f488576c000)
        libcrypt.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcrypt.so.2 (0x00007f488572f000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f488569d000)
```

libpthread, for example, which also is in `lib64`, is found:

```
gcc -L /lib64 -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: in function `_start':
```

Am I missing something or should this normally be found right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-lpq` causes the linker to look for `libpq.so`, with no soname suffix. To provide this on Fedora, you should install `libpq-devel`:

```
sudo dnf install libpq-devel
```